# Drupal 9 - Load library from code snippet module

Tags: module, code-snippets, ckeditor4.x, drupal-9

I am stuck on an issue. I have installed codesnippet module in Drupal 9. I am aware that we have to upload this into /libraries root folder.

My problem is that on on my local dev environment, it is working fine. But to push this on production server, I need to include this codesnippet files through code which I have uploaded to /libraries folder.

I have read lot of documentations related attaching js and CSS files. But how can I load the library which exists in /libraries root folder in my theme. Does anybody know this? Any help would be appreciated

I have tried through theme theme_libraries.yml file but it is loading the files which exists in specific theme. But I have to load the full library which exists in /libraries root folder